# RegEx for excluding a capture group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've tried for a few hours to devise a regex for this but haven't been able to.

Here is the line I'm searching over. I need to extract only the `[Name] Action Detail` portion.

```
2019-05-14 11:28:08,257 [tomcat-http--12] INFO  com.my.org.SomeClass  - Usage Event: ,SomeField=null,SomeOtherField=Some value,Action=[Name] Action Detail,OtherField=null
```

This regex gives me *almost* what I need: `Action=\[[^,]+`. However, I need to exclude the `Action=` part. I'm thinking to do so I need to use a nested subgroup?

Comment: Either use positive lookbehind or put your intended text in group1 and capture from group1 `Action=(\[[^,]+)`

Comment: You can use `(?<=Action=)`, or `Action=\K`, but not sure if your engine will parse any of those, which language are you using?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes splunk

Comment: `^(?:[^=\n]*=){5}(?P<Action>\[[^,]+)` seems to be working, but I'm not sure I understand it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: According to this page [splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.6/SearchReference/Rex) uses PCRE. Try `Action=\K\[[^,]+` https://regex101.com/r/ndwwrr/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a capturing group around Action= and it would do so:

```
(Action=)\[[^,]+
```

You can also extend it with another capturing group around your desired output to simply extract that:

```
(Action=)(\[[^,]+)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

You can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gdi3a7/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(Action=)(\[[^,]+)/gm;
const str = `2019-05-14 11:28:08,257 [tomcat-http--12] INFO  com.my.org.SomeClass  - Usage Event: ,SomeField=null,SomeOtherField=Some value,Action=[Name] Action Detail,OtherField=null`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: this is for a extracted field in splunk